# Include a file and replace it

Tags: php, caching, include, exit

I have a caching function and got HTML files.

Problem is I want to include my file into my page.

**Example :**

```
<h2>Before</h2>
<?php
cache('start');
// content....
cache('end');
?>
<footer>After</footer>
```

So my cache's function is so simple like...

```
function cache($a,$min=null) {
    global $cachefile;
    $cache_path = "/cached/";
    $file_name = basename(rtrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/'));
    $file_path = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $cachefile = $cache_path.sha1($file_path).'.cache';
    if($a == 'start'){
        $lifetime = $min * 60;
            if(file_exists($cachefile)&&time()-$lifetime<filemtime($cachefile)){
                include($cachefile);
                exit;
            }
            ob_start();
    }
    if($a == 'end'){$fp=fopen($cachefile,'w');fwrite($fp,ob_get_contents());fclose($fp);ob_end_flush();}
}
```

**Problem is ...**

```
include($cachefile);
exit;
```

It's stop rendering after included. I tried to remove `exit` so I got 2 multiple contents.

Any ?

Comment: just put your function `cache` in a global utils file and include it once

Comment: are you getting any error or page blank

Comment: No any error, I just want to replace all content between `cache('start');` and `cache('stop');`  @NanheKumar

Comment: When I use `exit;`it's mean stop render more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im done now :D

```
function cache($a,$min=null) {
    global $cachefile;
    $cache_path = get_template_directory()."/cached/";
    $file_name = basename(rtrim($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/'));
    $file_path = 'http'.(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])?'':'s').'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $cachefile = $cache_path.sha1($file_path).'.cache';
    $lifetime = $min * 60;
    if($a == 'start'){
            if(file_exists($cachefile)&&time()-$lifetime<filemtime($cachefile)){
                include_once($cachefile);
            }
            ob_start();
    }
    if($a == 'end'){
        if(file_exists($cachefile)&&time()-$lifetime<filemtime($cachefile)){
            ob_end_clean();
        } else {
            $fp=fopen($cachefile,'w');
            fwrite($fp,ob_get_contents());
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
}
```

So do like this...

```
<h2>Before</h2>
<?php
cache('start',10);
// content....
cache('end',10);
?>
<footer>After</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `include_once`. It will force the the include to only run once. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Let me try , just a min

Comment: nope , dose'nt work :(

Comment: `include_once($cachefile); exit;` right ?

Comment: Nope , Page ended after `cache('end');` :(